# Two 3D vectors having same magnitude are taken. What is the average of all possible values of a relative velocity vector(magnitude) of these vectors?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

Two 3D vectors of same magnitude are given. Only their unit vector can me manipulated. What would be the average value of all possible relative velocity vectors(Difference of the two vectors) formed by the two vectors of same magnitude(take magintude of initail vectors as x)?

The following question was asked my my professor with no more context

I tried taking two fixed vectors first but could not comprehend result for all directions

My professor also told to think what could be the average unit vector of our relative velocity like vector.

Comment: What is a "velocity like vector"?  This isn't very clear.

Comment: I was referring to relative velocity vector, will edit to clarify

Comment: That still doesn't make sense.

Comment: By "relative velocity vector," do you mean the difference between the two vectors?

Comment: Basically, you can rotate the two identical vectors(consider them as velocities), they have same magnitude. Now the question asks what would be the average magnitude of all possibe relative velocity vectors formed by our two identical velocity vectors

Comment: Yes whpowell96, should have clarified in question.  My apologies

Comment: I still don't understand.  Given two vectors, there are only two possible differences:  $a-b$ and $b-a$.

Comment: Both vectors have same magnitude, lets say 10 units, so their difference will change with variation of angel between them

Comment: So i am having difficulty finding average of all possible differences aka relative velocities

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The expected distance between two points on a sphere and on a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4209167/the-expected-distance-between-two-points-on-a-sphere-and-on-a-circle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\vec{u}$ denote the fixed vector and $\vec{v}$ denote the varying vector. We are interested in the average of the quantity $\vec{w} = \vec{v}-\vec{u}$ where $\vec{v}$ is uniformly distributed over a sphere.

Notice that since $\vec{v}$ is uniformly distributed over a sphere, its average must be the zero vector by symmetry. The average of the fixed vector $\vec{u}$ is just itself. Taking averages (expectation) is a linear operation, so we simply add these averages to obtain

$$\vec{w}_{av} = \vec{v}_{av} - \vec{u}_{av} = \vec{0} - \vec{u} = -\vec{u}.$$

Comment: Your reasoning seems correct and thus the answer must be the magnitude of -u vector

Comment: Thank you for the assistance